# I don't receive any MMS on Ubuntu Touch mx4

Tags: ubuntu-touch, mms

I'm using Ubuntu Touch on meizu mx4. My phone operator is free mobile and I am on OTA5 version.

I can send mms,  but I'm unable to receive any MMS. Wifi on or off does not change anything.

Any idea to fix this issue?

EDIT: On OTA6 release this bug is still not solved! :-(

EDIT2: On OTA6, I found out that to be able to receive a MMS, one should enable data connexion (3G/4G) otherwise the mms notification SMS is discarded. On android this is not the case. Even with 3G/4G disable, you do get this notification SMS which ask you to download the MMS. With that notification, you enable 3G/4G and go ahead with the download.
On Ubuntu touch, if someone would like to send you a MMS, he or she have to send you prior to the MMS, a SMS, asking you to enable the 3G/4G. That's not very convenience....!

Answer (score 0):

The issue are going to be resolved, just check https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/messaging-app/+bug/1439101 for advancement.